# Getting no pagebreaks in numbered paragraph mode using eledmac

Tags: page-breaking, paragraphs, eledmac

Could someone help with getting no page breaks while typing 4 line-paragraphed texts in `\pstart` and `\pend` paragraph groups in eledmac. I'm typesetting a multilingual critical edition using XeLaTeX (memoir, book, two-sided) and would like each paragraph to be completely contained on a page.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be easier for us to reproduce your situation and find the issue when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in posts. It is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to be concise. [Accepting/upvoting answers is the preferred way](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is now way to say to have a full paragraph not broken, because that has no sense if a paragraph is longer than a page.

Indeed, in "normal" LaTeX there is also no way to have this behavior. The only way is to add a `\nopagebreak` to prevent page breaking in some point. In `eledmac`, there is `\lednopb` command. Its use is quite complex. I invite you to read the handbook (section "Page breaks").

Comment: I noticed in a test, that a single line of a longer paragraph was put on the next page. Is there a way to get `eledmac` compatible with `nowidow` (or exactly the based plain LaTeX commands)? This would help the OP I think. `nowidow` with option `all` broke the appearance, without this option no effect was to be seen. With an explicit `\nowidow` errors appear.

Comment: @speravir: could you send a mwe?

Comment: Done. Sent to address given in documentation. The error is because of `\autopar`, though.